# ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

I have tried the following query but its showing an error as `error:ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

```
 SELECT OUTLET_NAME  FROM OUTLET_DETAILS 
where outlet_name in (12TH MAIN,17TH CROSS MALLESWARAM);
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

you need the quotes around `'12TH MAIN','17TH CROSS MALLESWARAM'`